# If $d(A,B) = \inf_{a \in A, b \in B}{d(a,b)}$ , does $d(A, B) ≤ d(A, C) + d(C, B)? $

Tags: metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

I´m trying to prove that if we define the distance between two sets $A, B$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ in the following way:

$$
 d(A,B) = \inf_{a \in A, b \in B}{d(a,b)}
$$

It verifies that  $\phantom{30}d(A, B) ≤ d(A, C) + d(C, B)$

The question seems very easy but I have problems to solve it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, consider $$A=[0,1], B=[2,3], C=[1,2].$$